# Non-Background Responsive Images in CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, web-frontend

My images are taking on its entire dimensions-- spanning the page to the point where you have to scroll right to see the image. I do not want this.

[Screenshot Of Web Browser View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhWX9.jpg)

I would like for my images to neatly fit within the webpage and respond to the size of the page, without scrolling to the right.

I plan to have multiple images on the page with text at the top, like so...

[multiple images idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gX08.png)

Here is my current code. I've been trying different alternatives, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My CSS code:

```css
#carousel {
  position: absolute;
}
```

My HTML code:

```html
<div id="carousel" align="center">
        <img src="../images/....jpg" />
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#carousel img { width: 100% }` or `#carousel img { object-fit: cover }` to your CSS?

Comment: Omg, that was the answer! Wow. I probably overcomplicated things. Thank you so much @kmoser

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add either `#carousel img { width: 100% }` or `#carousel img { object-fit: cover }` to your CSS for responsive images.